# How do you exclude certain networks from logging in through Facebook connect

Tags: facebook

My question is how do you exclude certain networks from using facebook connect on your website. I mean if you want FB connect on your site, can you limit say only people with NYU.edu Emails or people in the NYU network?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the [auth.revokeAuthorization](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Auth.revokeAuthorization) command (PHP) after authenticating them and then checking their network.

Comment: Although, this might fall under the 'users must not be suprised' guideline.

Comment: Easily solved with "NYU students only" wording above the button.